# Unity - Generated sprite not visible on iOS

Tags: c#, ios, sprite, unity-game-engine

currently i'm downloading an image from web via WWW. That works perfect for all targeted platforms excepting iOS.
On iOS the image appears just black.

Here is the code:

```
public void receiveData(WWW receivedData)
{
    image.sprite = Sprite.Create(receivedData.texture, new Rect(new Vector2(0,0), new Vector2(50, 50)), new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f));
    image.color = Color.white;
}
```

I've been trying around for some time now without any results...
F.E. i tried to change the format of the texture with textureFormat or creating a new Texture2D and changed the pixel. But all results in a black image.
Does anyone have an idea what the matter is?

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

It is likely black because the `WWW` is not yet finished downloading on iOS. That code should be in a coroutine function and you have to wait with `yield return receivedData`. If this does not solve your problem, you have to post the rest of your code but this is likely the problem.

```
public IEnumerator receiveData(WWW receivedData)
{
    //Wait to finish downloading image
    yield return receivedData;

    //You can now create sprite from the data image
    image.sprite = Sprite.Create(receivedData.texture, new Rect(new Vector2(0,0), new Vector2(50, 50)), new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f));
    image.color = Color.white;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't solve the problem. receiveData is called with the result of the mentioned coroutine. Errors are handled there too.

Comment: @MadCaddie82 Ok. So post the rest of the code. We can't help without that.

Answer (score 0):

How large is the image? Is it possible you are exceeding the maximum allowed image size for the hardware?

Comment: Thanks. The smallest size i've been using was 50x50 Pixel. Hope thats not too much for an iPhone6 ;)